# ActionResult parameter always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Im trying to define a RouteAttribute in my Controller but the value is always hitting null. Stuff i tried:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("User/ChangePassword/{code:guid}")]
 public ActionResult ChangePassword(Guid code)
 {
     return View();
 }

 URL:
 http://localhost:59635/User/ChangePassword/c809619-4451-4e60-86ca-3bf7159c6d15
```

Im getting this code always null, even if i put a string. 
Ps. The parameter is required and no optional, any ideas?

Comment: And your URL looks like this? `http://yoursite/user/changepassword/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012`

Comment: @NickAlbrecht yes, thats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your call to register the attribute routes comes before you register the default (or area) routes. Should look something like this...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```